# ¿Cómo cambiar cada elemento del cuadro de listBox con un color diferente?

Tags: c#

Necesito cambiar el color de fondo de cada elemento del cuadro de listBox o el color del texto, estoy usando esta función, funciona pero establece todos los elementos en el mismo color

```
    private void listBox2_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
        e.DrawBackground();
        var authorsList = Regex.Split(rgbColor, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
        var myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(Int32.Parse(authorsList[0]), Int32.Parse(authorsList[1]), Int32.Parse(authorsList[2])));

        e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
              e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069356/579895). Básicamente, deberías crear una clase que contenga el color de cada elemento, y de esa manera podrás en `DrawItem` definir de que color debes pintarlo.

Comment: Coloqué una respuesta argumentada explicativa, para tu problema. Espero que pruebes lo que te coloque en la respuesta debe resultarte, pues lo he usado y es algo básico y elemental, espero además que tengas la amabilidad de puntar mi respuesta, seria un estimulo para mi, pues soy usuario nuevo y además desarrollador autodidacta

Answer (score 0):

Es evidente que estas dibujando todos los items del mismo color, el evento `listBox2_DrawItem` ocurre cada ves que se dibuja un item del `ListBox`, el color lo cambia el procedimiento `e.Graphics.DrawString`, pero cada ves que ocurre tu le pasas el mismo argumento `Brush` que asignaste a la variable `myBrush` te daras cuenta que si ese argumento es siempre igual, el color será el mismo, tendrias que introducir algún método en tu código que cambie `myBrush` segun cambie el item dibujado.
Te brindo un ejemplo.

```
private void listBox2_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
            e.DrawBackground();
            //Definir el color predeterminando de tu objeto Brush en black.
   Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;

   //Determinar el color e tu objeto Brush para cada item basado en el index del item a dibujar.
   switch (e.Index)
   {
      case 0:
         myBrush = Brushes.Red;
         break;
      case 1:
         myBrush = Brushes.Orange;
         break;
      case 2:
         myBrush = Brushes.Purple;
         break;
   }
     e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
```

El ejemplo está limitado a tres items, pero hay infinidad de variantes para establecer colores diferentes a cada items, pudieras implementar una opción para que los items con Index impar tengan un color y los par otro, pudieras generar tres números aleatorios de 0 a 255 y definir un color RGB para tu objeto `Brush` en cada llamada al evento.